# Split string to columns using text as column headers and column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that has 1 column where each row contains a string. It looks like this:

```html
df
          data
in 9.14  out 9.66  type 0.0
in 9.67  out 9.69  type 0.0
in 9.70  out 10.66 type 0.0
in 10.67 out 11.34 type 2.0
in 11.35 out 12.11 type 2.0
```

I want to split the text of this column into multiple columns. I want to use the words [in, out, type] as column headers, and the values following each word as the row values. The result will have 3 columns labeled in, out and type and will look like this:

```html
        df
        
         in    out   type
        9.14   9.66   0.0
        9.67   9.69   0.0
        9.70   10.66  0.0
        10.67  11.34  2.0
        11.35  12.11  2.0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance what the words will be, and also can guarantee that there won't be any  bad data, this is a simple `str.extract` problem, where you can construct a robust regular expression to capture each group, using named groups to create the DataFrame in a single pass.  That regular expression for your sample data is contained in approach #2.

However, for the sake of demonstration, it is better to assume that you might have bad data, and that you might not know in advance what your column names are.  In that case, you can use `str.extractall` and some `unstack`ing.

***Option 1***
`extractall` + `set_index` + `unstack`

```
generic_regex = r'([a-zA-Z]+)[^0-9]+([0-9\.]+)'

df['data'].str.extractall(generic_regex).set_index(0, append=True)[1].unstack([0, 1])
```

```
0         in    out type
match      0      1    2
0       9.14   9.66  0.0
1       9.67   9.69  0.0
2       9.70  10.66  0.0
3      10.67  11.34  2.0
4      11.35  12.11  2.0
```

---

***Option 2***
Define an explicit regex and use `extract`

---

```
rgx = r'in\s+(?P<in>[^\s]+)\s+out\s+(?P<out>[^\s]+)\s+type\s+(?P<type>[^\s]+)'

df['data'].str.extract(rgx)
```

```
      in    out type
0   9.14   9.66  0.0
1   9.67   9.69  0.0
2   9.70  10.66  0.0
3  10.67  11.34  2.0
4  11.35  12.11  2.0
```

Comment: Thank user3483203 , unfortunately, the code splits the columns appropriately, but all of the data turns into 'NaN". Please advise.

Comment: user3483203 thanks for the more detailed response. I understand what is going on more, but the generic approach doesn't yield any result. The code runs fine, but the output is empty.

Comment: Is the sample dataframe that you shared similar to your actual dataframe?

Comment: Got it, thanks. The generic approach worked. My actual dataframe had a slight difference that once I fixed, everything worked. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you data separated evenly between `name` and `value` by white-spaces as in your sample , you may use `split` and `str` accessor with stride to construct the desired output

```
df1 = df['data'].str.split()
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df1.str[1::2].tolist(), columns=df1[0][0::2])

Out[1097]:
      in    out type
0   9.14   9.66  0.0
1   9.67   9.69  0.0
2   9.70  10.66  0.0
3  10.67  11.34  2.0
4  11.35  12.11  2.0
```